# System.Data.SQLite Logic error in select command

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have the following select command:

```
        Dim nCmdSel As SQLite.SQLiteCommand = cnApp.CreateCommand
        With nCmdSel
            .CommandText = "SELECT word, priority FROM mf WHERE word LIKE " & _
                "@word% " & _
                "ORDER BY priority DESC LIMIT 100"
            .Parameters.Add("@word", DbType.String).Value = sThisWord 
        End With
        r = nCmdSel.ExecuteReader()
```

I am getting the error

```
"SQL logic error near ORDER:"
```

But I don't see where I made a mistake.
Does anybody see it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

I need to do it like this:

```
.Parameters.Add("@word", DbType.String).Value = sThisWord & "%"
```